# Can I apply vertical-align to an image inside an absolute positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div and an image inside it, can I vertically allign the image to the center of the previous div? It might look like a repost and actually might be, but i couldn't find an answer to suit me.

```
    <div id="filteredImgContainer">
        <img id="loading" src="images/loader.gif" height="328" alt="" />
    </div>
```

css:

```
#filteredImgContainer {
    height: 328px;
    width: 251px;
    max-height: 328px !important;
    max-width: 251px !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 340px;
    top: 196px;
}



.filteredImg {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-height: 328px !important;
    max-width: 251px !important;
}
```

Comment: To clarfiy: do you want to center `.filteredImg` inside `filteredImgContainer`?

Comment: [Understanding Vertical Align](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/)

Comment: Wrap image in another div with position relative and height and width same as #filteredImgContainer. Than for .filteredImg to align in center, `position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; margin-top: - heightOfImage/2; margin-left: -widthOfImage/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i've tried this and it worked:**

```
#filteredImgContainer
{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   max-height: 328px !important;
   max-width: 251px !important;
   position: absolute;
   border:solid 1px black;
}
#loading
{
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: If the image has the .filteredImg class as I suspect, being a block element (as per it's css), vertical alignement will have no effect.

Comment: @alou according to css provided, it is block. `.filteredImg { display:block; ..`

Answer (score 0):

If you set `.filteredImgContainer > img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }` That should align the element to the middle of the containing `div`. Then you can style the containing `div` to move the image where you want it to go.

If your `img` element is meant to have the class `.filteredImg` then change `display: block` to `display: inline-block` and add your `vetical-align: middle;`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following after your CSS rules will align the image to center

```
#filteredImgContainer:before{width: 1px; display: inline-block; height: 328px; vertical-align: middle; content: ''; margin-left: -1px;}
#loading{ vertical-align: middle; }
```